# AzureWebJobsScriptRoot variable is not defined on Azure Functions, but returns correct value locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions

AzureWebJobsScriptRoot variable is not defined on Azure Functions. The code below returns no value.
 `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)["AzureWebJobsScriptRoot"];`

However, `%HOME%\site\wwwroot` will be returned based on below:

[AzureWebJobsScriptRoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsscriptroo)

> AzureWebJobsScriptRoot
>
> The path to the root directory where the host.json file and function folders are located. In a function app, the default is %HOME%\site\wwwroot.
>
> Key            Sample value
>
> AzureWebJobsScriptRoot    %HOME%\site\wwwroot

It returns correct value locally, not %HOME%\site\wwwroot

**Update**

Is this a bug with Azure Functions?

If so, what is an alternative solution?

Before the issue is fixed by Microsoft, can this variable, `AzureWebJobsScriptRoot`, be defined myself to `"%HOME%\site\wwwroot"` on Azure?

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1146
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26761

Answer (score 0):

I test in my site and get the same problem with you. As the [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Configuration-Settings) said, when running in Azure, will default to `%HOME%\site\wwwroot` and it set the function folder under `home\site\wwwroot`.

However, when I set `AzureWebJobsScriptRoot` in Azure funtion `Application Settings`, it will show in the output like below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think this is a bug. This variable is system variable, which must exist and cannot be defined by user

Comment: you should use my link on OP, your link is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure a function app with a different value for `AzureWebJobsScriptRoot`, then the functions host should honor that new value. For example, if you set `AzureWebJobsScriptRoot = D:\home\site\wwwroot\foo` then the functions host would look for a host.json file and function directories in the D:\home\site\wwwroot\foo location.

By default, this environment variable is not set. So it is expected that if you did not set it yourself, then `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsScriptRoot")` will return null.

Be aware that if you modify this setting, other components like the portal, visual studio, visual studio code, etc will not be aware of setting and will deploy your code to the normal default location. If you want to customize this setting, its up to you to make sure the application code is deployed to the right location.

Please refer the full details [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26761)

Comment: Don't you think this is a bug with Azure Function? The variable returns correct value locally, but it is NOT defined on Azure Function when it is documented its default value of the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsscriptroo

Comment: Based on what you said that changing the value of this variable will cause issues with the portal, VS, etc, Microsoft should make it apparent, at least document it on its offical document, and should recommend not to change it.